# Why does Cloudflare Analytics show a larger number of visitors to my website than Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, cloudflare

I am using CloudFlare to sit in front of my website and I am also using Google Analytics within my site.

I always seem to see a much large number of visitors and from a diverse set of locations in my CloudFlare analytics portal than I do in the Google Analytics equivelent.

Is it the case that CloudFlare records Bots and Spider visits whereas Google Analytics only records page impression loaded via a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out with this question on Quora and had an Engineer from CoudFlare respond with the below:

> 'Because the CDN answers most queries from the cache and reaches out
>   to the origin only when it has to fetch dynamic content. The requests
>   you see in cloudflare includes both static and dynamic Content served,
>   where as in google it is only dynamic content that the origin
>   answered'